# How can I add footers to Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have to export *a single tab* of my spread sheet as PDF document.

Is there a way to print the user name/current date etc. in the document footer?

When exporting the document, I cannot find any options to add this information.
Furthermore, I would like to add these data by default for all PDF exports, the same way it is possible with OpenOffice or Microsoft Office.

Comment: Could you make your comment an answer to my question, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only option is to create a Google Doc, write code that would put spreadsheet data into a Doc table, with footer, then save the Doc as a PDF